# Build with parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a script which runs a Jenkins job using buildWithParameters. The values given here contain "#" and this character is recognized as a comment, not as a character from that value:

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters?token=token&var1=test#1&var2=test#2
```

In job var1 is test and var2 has no value.

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The "#" was replaced with "%23", the hex code of #.

```
http://jenkins:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters?token=token&var1=test%231&var2=test%232
```